# user c# method with logical or from powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm using a function written in c# as follow

```
public bool FileExists(string path, FtpListOption options)
```

I use this function withing c# with no problem,

But when I try to use it from powershell, I get a problem

```
$reply = $conn.FileExists("TestRootDir/TestFile5.txt", [System.Net.FtpClient.FtpListOption]::ForceList | [System.Net.FtpClient.FtpListOption]::AllFiles);
```

The problem resides on the logical or, it works fine when I'm using one option,

I tried to replace the "|" with "-OR"
but I get another problem which says

that it can't convert the value `True` into `System.Net.FtpClient.FtpListOption`

Can someone guide me please to solve this issue?

Comment: use `-bor` instead (binary OR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-or` is a conditional operator, expecting arguments that evaluate to either `$true` or `$false`.

For a binary/numerical OR operator, use the binary OR operator (`-bor`):

```
$options = [System.Net.FtpClient.FtpListOption]::ForceList -bor [System.Net.FtpClient.FtpListOption]::AllFiles
$conn.FileExists("TestRootDir/TestFile5.txt", $options)
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been said in a comment, I appreciate the help
and I'm accepting your answer

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)